# listings Package : disable " string delimiter

Tags: listings

I am making slides for my students, and I use the listings package

I want to display warning and error messages given when compiling basic erroneous C code.

A typical error I have trouble displying is to forget to close a string delimiter. The warning you get is

```
Errors1.c:5:16: warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
    printf("the value of x is %i,x);
```

The problem when I write in in LateX using listings package is that it sees the first " as the beginning of a string delimiter, so everything that follows is formatted as a string.

See below a MWE. Everything after the " is interpreted as a string (visible spaces and italic). (Sorry I don't know how to display compiled latex here)

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{bash}{
language=bash,
breaklines=true, 
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
stringstyle=\textit,
morekeywords={warning,error},
showspaces=false,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=bash]
Errors1.c:5:16: warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        printf("the value of x is %i,x);
               ^
Errors1.c:5:16: error: expected expression
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for helping me

Pierre

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]. To display a result, you can take a screenshot of your compiled document and embed it into your post.

Comment: To me there is something strange about your choice of language here. You are not displaying something from the `bash` language, but an output into the `bash` shell. I'd probably just ignore `bash` as a language here as this is not displaying the code for a `bash` script.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as asked: you can ignore string delimiters using the `deletestring` style option. This option should reflect the original definition of the delimiter, which for `bash` and `sh` includes the `[d]` escape mode, i.e., a literal `"` within a string can be escaped by [d]oubling it. Escaping the character within a string does not help you here, because you are not in a string, but you need to know it in order to properly remove the delimiter from the language definition.

However, if you are not using syntax highlighting then you can also use a verbatim environment. When the input contains long lines then you can use the `Verbatim` environment (note the upper case V) with the `breaklines` option from the package `fvextra`/`fancyvrb`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\lstdefinestyle{bash}{
language=bash,
breaklines=true, 
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
stringstyle=\textit,
morekeywords={warning,error},
showspaces=false,
deletestring=[d]"
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=bash]
Errors1.c:5:16: warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        printf("the value of x is %i,x);
               ^
Errors1.c:5:16: error: expected expression
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{Verbatim}[breaklines=true]
Errors1.c:5:16: warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        printf("the value of x is %i,x);
               ^
Errors1.c:5:16: error: expected expression
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]